# UILabel shows dot after typing some texts

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I have a UILabel which is implemented in a UIToolbar to display a number of text count.

[image]

The problem is if user starts typing and text count reaches more than 10, label shows dot dot dot.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Below is my label code

```
    let textCountLabel: UILabel = {
    let lb = UILabel()
    lb.text = "0/2000"
    lb.textColor = .lightGray
    lb.sizeToFit()
    return lb
}()

func createToolBar(){
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(customView: anonymousButton)
    )
    items.append(
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    )
    items.append(
        UIBarButtonItem(customView: textCountLabel)
    )
    toolBar.setItems(items, animated: true)

    textFieldPost.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

Comment: The label isn't big enough for the longer text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your **textCountLabel**, also update the size or font to fit the text in your predefined space. see the sample code.

```
textCountLabel.text =  yourUpdatedString
textCountLabel.sizeToFit()
```